# Problem with scipy.optimize.newton(): "Add" object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm writing a function that takes 2 lists and creates a polynomial function to later be solved by optimization.

I'm trying to create a string that looks like a function, convert it into a function by using `sympy.sympify()` and then pass it into `optimize.newton()`.

However it keeps throwing a `TypeError "Add" object is not callable` while I already think that `sympify` has correctly returned a function.

I think I'm missing something very basic, maybe there is a function to turn my variable `function0` into a function type for `scipy` to interpret correctly maybe?

```
def poly_build(coefficient_list, power_list):
    '''
    coefficient_list & power_list must be iterable objects of the same length, preferably a list
    '''
    if len (coefficient_list) != len(power_list):
        return False
    function = ""
    for n in range(0, len(coefficient_list)):
        if n != len(coefficient_list) - 1:
            function += f'{coefficient_list[n]}*x**{power_list[n]} +'
        else:
            function += f'{coefficient_list[n]}*x**{power_list[n]}'
    function0 = (sympy.sympify(function))
    function1 = sympy.diff(function0)
    function2 = sympy.diff(function1)

    return scipy.optimize.newton(function0, 1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sympy function isn't a Python function as `scipy.optimize.newton` expects it. To convert:

```
pyfunction0 = sympy.lambdify(x, function0)
```